# How to find last active day for each user in SQL?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a table which looks like this:

| date | user_id | active_dt | last_active_day |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | 1 | null | null |
| 2020-01-02 | 1 | null | null |
| 2020-01-03 | 1 | null | null |
| 2020-01-04 | 1 | 2020-01-05 | null |
| 2020-01-05 | 1 | 2020-01-08 | 2020-01-05 (as of 2020-01-05, the last actve date was 2020-01-05). |
| 2020-01-06 | 1 | null | 2020-01-05 (as of 2020-01-06, the last active date was 2020-01-05). |
| 2020-01-07 | 1 | null | 2020-01-05 (as of 2020-01-07, the last active date was 2020-01-05). |
| 2020-04-18 | 1 | null | 2020-01-08 (as of 2020-04-18, the last active date was 2020-01-08). |

Answer (score 1):

You can use **MAX** and **GROUP BY**:

```
SELECT user_id, MAX(last_active_day) FROM table_name GROUP BY user_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple

```
SELECT user_id, last_active_day
FROM table_name
WHERE last_active_day IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY last_active_day DESC
```

query.